# How to stream an mp3 over web?

Tags: html, mp3

How can I stream an MP3 in a html page? I am looking for a solution, which does not allow user to download of MP3 content, while allowing user to play it.

Comment: Stream how? To do what? Do you want to use a player? Please add much more detail

Comment: I am open to anything as long as it does not allow download of mp3

Comment: You may not realize it, but for playing, the user needs to download the music data. What you want is sucky DRM.

Comment: Nothing can prevent a knowledgeable user from getting the audio in a file, not even real live streaming because even that can be recorded digitally (no degradation in copy) and edited. The only thing you can do if you want to protect the audio (e.g. force an interested user to buy it) is to make it hard to download (so most users can't) and possibly, as many sites do, stream the audio as a small fragment or in very low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash Player remains the best means of doing this if you want to reach the largest audience. [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) wouldn't be a bad choice.

Comment: This will stream the file, but won't prevent a knowledgeable user from figuring out the URL for the mp3 and downloading it.

Comment: @archbishop: Nothing will.

Answer (score 0):

**This way requires the Media Player Plugin**

---

Use ***Media Player object/embed code:*****

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="46">
<param name="fileName" value="http://www.domain.com/music/music.m3u">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="true">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<param name="Volume" value="-300">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://www.domain.com/music/music.m3u" name="MediaPlayer1" width=280 height=46 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300>
</OBJECT>
```

replace your playlist or MP3 File

```
<param name="fileName" value="http://www.domain.com/music/music.m3u">
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is not a cross-platform/browser solution.

Answer (score -1):

No one mentioned the `<audio>` tag?

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp